# Are there any radical approaches in CPU development?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu

I have a desktop PC with the CPU Intel I7-12700F with **180 TDP**, the CPU fan Zalman CNPS10X extreme, and Windows 11 and my problem is that The CPU cooling causes much noise when simple tasks are being performed; opening directories or windows, opening or closing small programs such as Notepad, Calculator, web browser, or when taking the PC out of sleep mode.

I am not a CS student, just a layman trying to understand if the desktop CPU development field is somewhat "stuck" in the past decades.

If desktop CPUs of the 2020's generally use more power than those of previous decades hence get hot faster and require more extensive and noisy cooling, I'd carefully assume that desktop CPUs of 2020's aren't essentially very different than those of the 90's and 80's.

Are there perhaps different **paradigms** to create essentially differently desgined desktop CPUs which may allow similar capabilities but with **fanless cooling** / passive cooling?
Currently, fanless cooling is nearly nonexistent when it comes to desktop CPUs. A notorious CPU cooling model, *Nofan CR-80EH* is aimed for desktop CPUs of no more than **80 Watt TDP** and I don't know if such CPUs are still manufactured.

I am coming to ask this ignorantly and by a possible false analogy to electricity production. If I am not mistaken, electricity production has had some radical engineering shifts from coal burning, such as producing electricity from water flow, wind flow, nuclear reaction (such as fission), solar panels (also heat but still a radical change) and who knows what future holds?

Is there any radical approach to develop desktop CPUs at least in theory or currently in research labs, that will allow completely silent / fanless desktop computers with CPU capabilities similar to those of current desktop CPUs?

By the way, why not creating a motherboards with several small general processers, each one with passive cooling?

Comment: You don't need a radical new paradigm to create fanless, passive cooled computers. My Apple MacBook Air is fanless and fully passively cooled, so is my iPhone, my Samsung Galaxy, all three of my iPads, my Kindle, and my WiFi router. Smart TVs are typically passively cooled, as are some gaming consoles, especially the handheld ones.

Comment: The majors in processor development (Intel, AMD, Qualcomm, Fujitsu...) are constantly looking for technologies to optimize their designs and invest millions (billions ?) in that. If they don't manufacture the motherboard of your dreams, it is probably because this has no economical interest (except in some niche markets, who knows...)

Comment: @JörgWMittag I have edited to emphasize that I ask solely on desktop computer CPUs.

Comment: @YvesDaoust are you sure that this is a matter of economical interest? I'm pretty sure that for the last 40 years people got somewhat frustrated from noisy desktop computers. Perhaps with just one current paradigm, fanless desktop computers are just impossible? I really can't tell.

Comment: Modern PCs aren't supposed to be loud all the time. Temporarily when the CPU is at high load, maybe. If yours is loud all the time, there is probably something wrong with the fan profile.

Comment: @cpuObtainer: "I ask solely on desktop computer CPUs" – There is no difference between the M1 chip in a MacBook Air or iPad Pro and the one in the Mac mini or iMac. There are plenty of fanless, passively cooled desktops. In fact, they are much easier to build than fanless, passively cooled phones or laptops because there is a lot more space available for radiative and convective cooling.

Comment: Don't be so obtuse ! As said by others, fanless computers are around since long. And the matter IS of commercial interest, that's unavoidable.

Comment: @harold either you meant something different or that's untrue, please have a look at: https://superuser.com/questions/1783826/cpu-fan-makes-strong-noise-when-opening-directories-small-programs-like-web-br

Comment: @JörgWMittag I have a 180 TDP CPU and I have thoroughly looked and found only one model of passive cooling for PCs available today `Nofan CR-80EH`. Care to share another?

Comment: @cpuObtainer: [Silentmaxx](https://silentmaxx.de/) has been building and selling fanless, passively cooled PCs for over 20 years. And they were just the first of dozens of hits that [came up on Google](https://google.com/search?q=fanless+desktop). It's really simple: fanless, passively cooled smartphones exist. Fanless, passively cooled desktops are *much easier* to build than fanless, passively cooled smartphones since there is a lot more space and mass you can use for convective and radiative cooling. So, it is really not surprising at all that fanless, passively cooled desktops exist.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I didn't mean "nettops" or "mini PCs" but desktop PCs in the regular sense. You won't find more then 1-2 modern ready PCs like that and you certainly can't mean **custom** modern PCs which has only one commercial cooling available (`Nofan CR-80EH`) and only for CPUs up to **80 TDP**. Again you stretch towards smartphones and again I have to bring use back to desktop PCs which is the **sole** context of my post.

Comment: @cpuObtainer: [Silentmaxx](https://silentmaxx.de/) has been building and selling fanless, passively cooled PCs for over 20 years, and they have office desktops, gaming desktops, video editing desktops, and servers. And they were just the first of dozens of hits that [came up on Google](https://google.com/search?q=fanless+desktop).

Comment: @JörgWMittag find me such a "desktop" which is a not a "nettop" or has a "high-end CUP" of more than **100 TDP**. This is what I meant to all along. If there are so many results as you sure, you sure can come up with just one.

Comment: @cpuObtainer: [Silentmaxx](https://silentmaxx.de/) has been building and selling fanless, passively cooled PCs for over 20 years, and they have office desktops, gaming desktops, video editing desktops, and servers, including ones with, for example, Intel Core i9-13900K or Intel Xeon Gold 6150. And they were just the first of dozens of hits that [came up on Google](https://google.com/search?q=fanless+desktop).

Comment: So you didn't come with even one example. I rest my case.

Comment: You are specifying a TDP (Thermal Design Power) of 100W or higher, . If you want to have a high TDP (why???) then that's fine, but in that case you need a fanless cooling solution in case the TDP is reached. If you want to have fanless **CPU** tech then the processor should have a *lower* TDP for the same performance. In that case a radical development could e.g. be optical or gallium-arsenide processors. For silicon there are known limits to what you can do to lower TDP. Possibly a clockless design could help, or advanced CPU features such as encryption & AI accelerators.

Comment: AMD sells plenty of CPU's with a 65W TDP, including e.g. the 5800X3D which allows for high performance gaming. Put a large heat sink & fan on top of those and you can build a near silent system. I know 'cause I have one. The stock CPU coolers are shit at high load. 65W is too much for passive cooling, unless you have room for a large kit next to your tower (liquid cooling).

Comment: For new paradigms: Search for the "Mill" processor. Not a commercial success unfortunately. I haven't yet made my 8 core laptop use more than 22 Watt, even with 8 threads running at full speed for many minutes.

Comment: @cpuObtainer: 100Watt TDP doesn't make a processor "high end" or "high performance", it just takes energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two areas of research to consider:

- [Reversible logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing), and in particular, [adiabatic circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_circuit). The idea here is to increase energy conservation as much as possible by not destroying information most of the time.
- [Asynchronous logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_circuit). The theory behind this is that the best CPU clock speed is no clock at all.

Answer (score 3):

This already exists.  [Mobile processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_processor) meet all of your requirements.

There is a fundamental, unavoidable tradeoff between power consumption and processing speed.  You can already buy CPUs that lie at different points along that tradeoff.  Companies like Intel, AMD, etc., market high-end CPUs that maximize processing speed, at the cost of consuming more power; these are typically called "desktop CPUs" for marketing purposes.  Companies like Apple, ARM, Intel, AMD, etc. also make CPUs that are designed to reduce power consumption, at the cost of somewhat lower processing speed; these are typically called "mobile CPUs" for marketing purposes.  If you build a CPU for desktops that achieves lower power consumption, low enough to build a desktop CPU, then it is considered a mobile CPU, for marketing purposes.

So the CPUs that are marketed as "mobile CPUs" already are exactly what you are looking for.

You can already build a fanless desktop, by using a mobile processor and other parts that have lower power consumption, and there are plenty of them that you can already buy today.  For instance, if you search for "fanless PC", you'll find many systems that you can buy right now.

Comment: But I want non "mobile CPU" desktop which is fanless. Why is that such a hard thing to get? For example, "fanless PC" as you mention will usually not have a CPU with more than **80 TPD**, but I want around 200 TDP fanless. Why is that impossible to get?

Comment: @cpuObtainer so you want a different cooler design rather than a different CPU